# How servertelemetry channel collects the data for wpf - offline?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-application-insights, wiki

I used server telemetry in my WPF. Basically, the data will be stored locally at **(%localAppData%\Microsoft\ApplicationInsights)** or temp folder **(%TMP%)**, but in this path, only the folder is created but there is no data is being in that folder....cn some please help out

```
try
{
    TelemetryClientSingleton.Instance.TrackPageView();// Online
}
finally
{
            ServerTelemetryChannel channel = new ServerTelemetryChannel();
            channel.Initialize(TelemetryConfiguration.Active);              
            TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel = channel;
            TelemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
            TelemetryClient.InstrumentationKey = "-----";
            TelemetryClient.TrackPageView("My Form Open");
            TelemetryClient.Context.User.Id = "user_Id";
            TelemetryClient.Context.Session.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            TelemetryClient.Context.Device.OperatingSystem = Environment.OSVersion.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What's the point of your `catch` block?

Comment: there is no point of catch block

Comment: can u plzz upvote my question @Klaus Gutter

Comment: can u plzz upvote my question  @SeM

Comment: I would upvote a question which is useful and clear, and shows some research effort. You did not even ask a question.